# Getting values of dynamically created elements returns empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div where `<a>` are dynamically created and removed inside it. I want to iterate through the children(`<a>`) of the div(`#skills`) and get the value of them. I did work it out. But when i iterate through them using each() it just return empty when i console log it. I Am new to JS and jquery and don't know what cause this issue
My div

```
<div id="skills"></div>
```

Dynamic elements that will be added is a anchor tag.

```
<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" value="MYSQL">MYSQL
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

There is also span class which provides the glyphicons. Here i want to get only the value of anchor tag. In ths case **MYSQL** which is dynamically created when the anchor tag is created.

```
var skills = new Array();
$('#skills a').each(function(){
skills = $(this).val();
console.log(skills);
});
```

I want to get each anchor tag values and add it to the array skills. But when i do this. It just prints numbers in the console. Like if 2 anchor tags are there 
2 is printed and if 5 then 5. without the anchor tag value. how do it go about this ?

Comment: `skills.push($(this).val());`

Comment: @SandeepNayak really?

Comment: @NaveenKumar `skills.push($(this).attr("value"));` should be way to go. Yet `value` attribute does not make sense on anchor element.

Comment: Then @Jai : your comment wont work either. skills.push($(this).attr("value")) have to work.

Comment: @VforVendetta sure. that won't but the edited one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that `value` attribute is not a valid attribute for anchors and you can't get the value straightly with `.val()` method. That is only available for form elements.

In your case you can simplify this more as using `.map()` which gives you an array out of a collection.

To make it a valid attribute you can use `data-*` attribute on your anchor element:

```
data-value="MYSQL"
```

Then in your js code with above update:

```
var skills = $('#skills a').map(function(){
   return $(this).data('value');
}).get();
console.log(skills);
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `value` is for `<button>`, `<input>` and `<option>` elements.

In this instance, instead of `value` and `.val()`, use:

```
- `data-value` and `.data('value')`
```

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).data('value'));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL0">MYSQL0
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL1">MYSQL1
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL2">MYSQL2
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL3">MYSQL3
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL4">MYSQL4
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>

<a name="skill_wanted[]" class="label label-default" data-value="MYSQL5">MYSQL5
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</a>
```